# Run Python script in VS Code, without including in the project?

Tags: python, visual-studio-code

I can run Python script in vscode if I add a folder containing the script and define a run task.

But I want to run Python script without adding whole folder in vscode and create separate task.
Or even I want to run some Python scripts which are located in different folders, and I dont want to open new vscode instance for every location and define tasks for each.

Assuming this must be possible, I first thought to define "global" tasks `%APPDATA%\Code\User\tasks.json`. But it is not recognized when I try to run task on a Python script.

So how to run Python script (or interpret any other script) without making new "project" and repeatedly creating same task each time I want to do that (without opening terminal and running the script, or course)?

Comment: Hi, I'm the author of the Python extension for VS Code, unfortunately this isn't supported in the extension.

Comment: @Don thanks for your reply and your work. Hopefully VS Code will re-balance to allow best of both worlds (IDE/editor) so that we wont have to work in projects just to run a script.

Comment: Hi, as this is an open source IDE, there's no reason someone else can't create such a feature. Or you could perhaps raise this request on VS Code github as a feature requets.

Comment: Good idea, I just did that: https://visualstudio.uservoice.com/forums/293070-visual-studio-code/suggestions/14901501-run-script-outside-workfolder :)